# Service and bootup code not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to create a service that will run on bootup, however when trying it in my emulator the log is not showing my message through log tag, so clearly something is wrong.

Here is my code.

service.java

```
public class service extends Service {


private static final String TAG = "myapp.mycomp";

public service() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
    public void run() {
/** something to do **/

        }
    };

    Thread service = new Thread(r);
    service.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service stopped");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, service.class);
    context.startService(myIntent);

}
```

}

XML manifest intent

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

XML manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Try to run in a real device.

Comment: That's not it, but thanks.